# Why I think Area51 needs an API.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area51

Okay, I have to admit that I never dreamed I would be advocating an API for Area51. But here I am doing it :)

I think we need an API for Area51. Granted, the whole concept of questions and answers is vastly different but here are my reasons for needing it:

- Applications that notify the user of comments, etc. would still have the same benefit on Area51. Users would know right away when someone has commented to them.
- It would be nice if we could pull the list of users off of Area51 sorted by rep., name, 
  etc.
- Last but not least, **there is currently no way to get the global reputation for a user.** On Area51, there is a 'combined flair' that, well, combines all of the rep. from all of the sites. However, **it includes Area51 rep.** There is no way to obtain this.

A slight mitigation for the last point would be to add a 'reputation' field to the `/users/{ID}/associated` method that lists global rep.

Comment: the associated query lists rep for each site so you can add them up yourself.

Comment: @Sruly: BUT it doesn't include Area51 in that list. So you can't really add them up.

Comment: right, that seems to be the issue.