# Area51 does not show up in the associated accounts query

Tags: support, associated, area51

Is this on purpose and if yes why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it currently does not.

This has been discussed before, and if you really think it needs to be included in the API, you can vote for my feature-request [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1234/why-i-think-area51-needs-an-api).