# Can I Drive the Area51 Process via the SO API?

Tags: discussion, website, area51

I am planning a new webapp.  I want to use an SE instance to power the community feature of the new webapp.

Since all SE sites must pass through the Area51 process, I would like to know if I could enable my webapp users to seed the area51 version of the SE instance?

Ultimately, I want to leverage the awesome SO product to *be* my webapp's community (e.g. community.mywebapp.com).

What does the community think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access Area51 through the API.
[Area51 does not show up in the associated accounts query](https://stackapps.com/questions/1517/area51-does-not-show-up-in-the-associated-accounts-query)
[Why I think Area51 needs an API.](https://stackapps.com/questions/1234/why-i-think-area51-needs-an-api)

And even if you could, there is no write access in the current API version.