# Add Area 51 Discussions to site list and account list

Tags: feature-request, api-v2.2, area51

While [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) is accessible via the API ([proof](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=area51.meta)), it is neither in the [list of sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) nor in the [list of associated accounts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users). I'm not sure how much work this would be to add? I understand Area 51 runs on an old code base and [can't be supported right now](https://stackapps.com/q/1234/34061) but Area 51 Discussions runs on the same software as the rest of the network.